# How to change corner of the button to different size?

Tags: android, xml

Here is my xml,

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners
    android:radius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"/>

<stroke android:width="2px"
    android:color="@color/white" /></shape>
```

**Image**
I what my edit text field to look like this
[image: Am trying to design like this E-mail field style]

Comment: Waiting for the perfect answer , thank you

Comment: _corner of the button to different size_ what did you mean by that? Can you show us what is that you expect it to be?

Comment: I want top left and bottom right of the field to be in rounded view but am not getting it  all corners are in rounded view i dont need like that i just want only two corners to be in rounded view

Comment: do you view all corners rounded in run time and in design time?

Comment: during run time am getting rounded corner

Comment: try removing android:radius

Comment: Ya now its working man...

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: create buttonshape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#7995A8"
android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="linear"
/>
<padding
android:left="dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

**step 2 : give drawable to Edittext**

```
<Edittext
android:id="@+id/angry_btn"

android:text="Button"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30sp"

android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="5"
/>
```